# In what cases is the CloudKit error CKErrorIncompatibleVersion sent?

Tags: ios, watchkit, cloudkit, tvos

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CKErrorCode) says that:

> **CKErrorIncompatibleVersion**
>
> The app version is less than the minimum allowed version.
>
> *Available in iOS 8.0 and later.*

But doesn't give much details on what context would cause this error to be received. There's no way to set a minimum allowed *app* version, as far as I know.

Comment: Translation: "The IOS version is less than the minimum allowed version for this app"

Comment: There is no additional documentation for that error code, and I have not yet seen that code in production so this is only a guess: Apple will introduce a CloudKit feature in the future which will allow you to tie a database schema to an app version, i.e. you could create a migration in the dashboard and say: "From now on, only users with app version 1.2 can access CloudKit". Users of app version 1.1 will then receive this error code. To prepare for such a case, you could make your app forward compatible and show an appropriate error message "Please upgrade" if you see this code.

Comment: Two years on, and there’s still no sign of this feature (as far as I can tell)...